Unable to Find SAP Olingo JPA Processor v4 Artifacts in Maven Repository
I'm trying to use OData 4 with Java, utilizing the Apache Olingo library. However, I've run into a roadblock. The Olingo library for OData v4 doesn't include any data access layer. I discovered that there is a library from SAP that provides this functionality, but unfortunately, it is not available in our internal Maven repository.
The official documentation suggests using the following SAP library for the data layer:
Apache Olingo OData v4
Here's the GitHub repository for the SAP Olingo JPA Processor v4:
GitHub - SAP Olingo JPA Processor v4
While following the tutorial for the JPA processor, I encountered an error when executing the Maven command:
mvn clean install archetype:update-local-catalog

The error message is as follows:
Could not find artifact com.sap.olingo:odata-jpa-spring-support:jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT: 
The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
com.sap.olingo:odata-jpa-processor:jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT (absent), 
com.sap.olingo:odata-jpa-processor-cb:jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT (absent), 
com.sap.olingo:odata-jpa-spring-support:jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT (absent): 
Could not find artifact com.sap.olingo:odata-jpa-processor:jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT

Question:
How can I resolve this issue and successfully include the necessary SAP Olingo JPA Processor v4 artifacts in my Maven build? Are there any alternative repositories or steps I should follow to get these artifacts?
Thank you for your help!

Yes you are right, seems like these artifacts are not released to maven central repo. They also have a github issue open on it
In the absence of it the only option is to clone the repository and mvn install it
This is put the artifacts in local maven repository. If your origination uses a central repository internally they will have to be put on to it for builds to pass on other machines
